# Grafana: x-axis text overlapped in Series mode

Tags: histogram, grafana, grafana-templating

I am using Grafana to build a histogram like below (Mode is Series, not Time).

The category text at the x-axis are overlapped. Is there a way to break each category text into two or more lines?

Also, why is it saying "data points outside time range"? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the legend by for example using `alias()` in your query. You can add html tags, for example `alias(Abnormal Sound<br>Detect)` will be displayed in two lines. Of course, it depends on your query if / how you can use this.

As for your second question, without a query I would assume, that your query has a missing `$timefilter` also ordering the result by time can help.